# Does Nativescript support Dynatrace?

Tags: performance, nativescript, dynatrace

I am having some performance issues on the application I developed and would like to pin down on the issue to resolve the same.

I have tried the XCODE profiler but not much luck there, so looking at Dynatrace as an option.

I have seen some plugin "nativescript-dynatrace" but the documentation is not complete, could someone guide me in this context?

If some one could guide me on how to use Dynatrace with Nativescript it would be of great help.

Comment: NativeScript supports everything Xcode / Objective C support. You should be able to use the iOS SDK for Dynatrace in NativeScript. There seems to be a [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-dynatrace) already, you may give that a try.

Comment: I need to know how this plugin works, unfortunately the document is incomplete. Could you please provide me with any insights on how this works? Thanks.